# how to change html file with url get id in php

Tags: ajax, node.js, phpunit

For example I have two html files sample1.html and sample2.html and I want to show them in one php file, like if I entered www.mydomain.com/index.php?show=sample1 will show the sampl1.html and ?show=sample2 will show sample2.html but in only one page

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
<? include($_GET['show'].".html"); ?>
```

It not the a secure answer but I think this is what you want...

Comment: Sir I know but I dont know how to explain my problem. I can only give another example. For example if we go www.facebook.com/settings from a desktop browser. Then there are genrel settings of our fb account and when we click on privacy or any other setting the page remain same but only setting tab changes. And also in browser url field www.facebook.com/settings changed to www.facebook.com/settings?tab=privacy . I want exactly that system in php

Comment: Oh ok! It's a client side feature. You must use Javascript for that, not PHP.

Show this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pKr8Y/

You can replace the .html to load an external resource :
$('#test').load('/test.html')

Will load the test.html into your DIV.